# tabela html shellscript

Tags: javascript, html, shell, shell-script

Galera, alguem que manja de shellscript tem noção de como criar esse script pedido na imagem a baixo? Estou fazendo uns exercicios com o tema, e esse meio que me pegou.

[image: Sheelscript]

Comment: Os comandos [grep](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Usando-grep-e-egrep) e [awk](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/AWK-Manipulacao-de-arquivos-de-texto/) são suficientes para resolver este problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta assim :

```
#!/bin/bash

# make_page -Sua Página

cat <<- _EOF_
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Minha Lista
        </title>
    </head>
<body>
    <span>Itens:</span>"
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li> 
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
_EOF_
```

Comment: Assim nao seria mesmo necessário o uso do grep e awk?

Comment: @MaylaCampos, não responde ao enunciado mas está cool!  +1 . Talvez substituir os item por `$A` e calcular A com base nos parámetros: `for a in "$@"; do A=$A"<li>$a</li>"; done`

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que o código html está em `file.html`,

```
grep -Po '<li>\K.*(?=</li>)' file.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção com sed:

```
sed -n '/item/p' file.html | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```